# how to calculate portfolio return series in matlab?

Tags: matlab, portfolio

i have asset return matrix(t*n) and asset weight vector(1*n) that t is number of obs for n asset.if asset return matrix be r(i) and asset weight vector b w(i), i want sum(r(i)*w(i)), i=1:n that is a t*1 matrix.how can i calculate it in MATLAB?

example:

```
x =

0.1400    0.2100    0.1800
0.1100    0.1200    0.1500
0.1700    0.1600    0.1700
0.1800    0.2100    0.1400

w =

0.3000    0.2000    0.5000
```

then i want this matrix:

```
R(1,1)=(0.14*0.3)+(0.21*0.2)+(0.18*0.5)=?

R(2,1)=(0.11*0.3)+(0.12*0.2)+(0.15*0.5)=?

R(3,1)=...

R(4,1)=...
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply multiply `x` by `w` transposed. Note that `.'` is the transpose, not `'`. So, what you want is simply:

```
x * w.'    
ans =

    0.1740
    0.1320
    0.1680
    0.1660
```

---

Otherwise, if you want to practice `bsxfun`:

Use [`bsxfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to take the product of `x` and `w` for each column, and [`sum(.., 2)`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html#bupr1fz) to sum along the second dimension, like this:

```
sum(bsxfun(@times, x, w),2)
ans =

    0.1740
    0.1320
    0.1680
    0.1660
```